# How to check if exists offset key in `ArrayIterator` and call function if not exists?

Tags: php

Example how i would like somethink like that:

```
<?php 
    class newArr extends ArrayIterator {
         public function __get($key) {
              if(preg_match('#test[0-9]+#', $key)) { 
                  return my::func($key); 
              }  else { 
                  return $this[$key];
              } 
         }
    }
    $d = new newArr();
    $d['test'] = 1;
    
    echo $d['test'];
    echo $d['test2'];
?>
```

i getting :

```
Warning: Undefined array key "test2" in /home/user/scripts/code.php on line 15
```

I want catch `offsetGet` not works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if the offset key exists in the ArrayIterator and to call a function if it does not exist, modify the "__get" magic method in your newArr class.

```
class newArr extends ArrayIterator {
    public function __get($key) {
        if ($this->offsetExists($key)) {
            return parent::__get($key);
        } elseif (preg_match('#test[0-9]+#', $key)) { 
            return my::func($key); 
        } else { 
            return null; // or any default value you prefer
        } 
    }
}

$d = new newArr();
$d['test'] = 1;

echo $d['test'];   // Output: 1
echo $d['test2'];  // Output: null (or your default value)
```

We are using **offsetExists()** to check if the offset key exists in the ArrayIterator and if it exists, the parent __get method is called. Use **offsetExists()** to avoid the "Undefined array key" warning. :)